# Forward the data to another server using sockets in Vb.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to test a scenario where one server accepts multiple connections or multiples clients.

The purpose is forwarded the data to another server with a different IP and different port. At the time of forwarding the data whenever I view different connections on the other server.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub ConectarTcp(ByVal id_gps As String, ByVal data As String)
    Try
        With WinSockClient                
            .IPDelHost = "192.168.5.8"
            .PuertoDelHost = 3030                
            .Conectar()
        End With            
        WinSockCliente.EnviarDatos(trama)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub Conectar()
    Dim tcpClnt As TcpClient
    Dim tcpThd As Thread 

    tcpClnt = New TcpClient()      

    tcpClnt.Connect(IPDelHost, PuertoDelHost)
    Stm = tcpClnt.GetStream()


    tcpThd = New Thread(AddressOf LeerSocket)
    tcpThd.Start()

End Sub



Public Sub EnviarDatos(ByVal Datos As String)
    Dim BufferDeEscritura() As Byte
    BufferDeEscritura = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Datos)
    If Not (Stm Is Nothing) Then
        'Envio los datos al Servidor 
        Stm.Write(BufferDeEscritura, 0, BufferDeEscritura.Length)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What error/issue do you have?

Comment: The error is that different connections are made and need to be the same ie to identify the connection to another server and send the data. Please add code